# Porque uma mesma expressão regular apresenta dois resultados diferentes para uma mesma string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Usei a mesma regex para verificar a mesma string várias vezes seguidas, mas os resultados foram diferentes:

```js
p = /[0?]{2,3}$/g;
console.log(p.test("000")); // true
console.log(p.test("000")); // false
console.log(p.test("000")); // true
console.log(p.test("000")); // false
console.log(p.test("000")); // true
console.log(p.test("000")); // false
```

[image: Screenshot do terminal]

Alguém poderia me explicar o motivo destes resultados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Tire a *flag* `g` que funciona (a letra "g" depois da barra):

```
p = /[0?]{2,3}$/
```

Repare que não tem mais o `g` no final.

## Resposta longa

Quando você usa a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags), isso afeta o comportamento da propriedade `lastIndex`. E segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex), o `lastIndex` indica a posição a partir da qual a busca será feita.

Ainda segundo a mesma documentação, se os métodos [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) ou [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) encontram um *match*, o valor do `lastIndex` é atualizado para a posição logo depois do trecho encontrado. Mudando um pouco seu código, podemos ver o que acontece:

```js
var p = /[0?]{2,3}$/g;
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 3
console.log(p.test('000')); // false
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 3
console.log(p.test('000')); // false
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 3
console.log(p.test('000')); // false
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
```

Podemos ver que inicialmente `lastIndex` é zero. Depois, a primeira chamada de `test` retorna `true`, pois a busca é feita a partir da posição zero (ou seja, do início da string), e por isso encontrou um *match*. Depois disso, `lastIndex` foi atualizado para `3` (a posição imediatamente após o trecho encontrado, que no caso são os três zeros).

Isso quer dizer que a segunda chamada de `test` irá começar a busca na posição 3 da string. Mas como a string só tem 3 caracteres (e portanto, só tem as posições 0, 1 e 2), então ela não encontra nada. E a documentação diz que se nada for encontrado, `lastIndex` é setado para zero. Por isso que a terceira chamada retorna `true`, porque agora a busca é feita a partir da posição zero (ou seja, do início da string). E como nesse caso ele encontra um *match*, `lastIndex` é novamente atualizado para 3. E por isso que a quarta chamada retorna `false`, e a quinta retorna `true`, e assim por diante.

---

Aliás, se a segunda string tivesse um trecho que corresponde à regex, mas que ficasse depois da posição 3, aí funcionaria:

```js
var p = /[0?]{2,3}$/g;
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 3

// os zeros ficam depois da posição 3, então a regex encontra
console.log(p.test('abcdefxyz 000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 13
```

Vale lembrar ainda que cada regex tem seu próprio `lastIndex`, então se vc criar outra, também funciona:

```js
var p = /[0?]{2,3}$/g;
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 3

// cria outra, com seu próprio lastIndex 
p = /[0?]{2,3}$/g;
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 3
```

Se bem que neste caso não faz sentido ficar recriando a mesma expressão várias vezes. É mais simples não usar a *flag* `g`, como indicado abaixo.

---

Se não usarmos a *flag* `g`, o valor de `lastIndex` nunca é atualizado, e por isso todas as chamadas de `test` funcionam:

```js
var p = /[0?]{2,3}$/;
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
console.log(p.test('000')); // true
console.log(p.lastIndex); // 0
```

A *flag* `g` faz sentido quando você quer buscar por todas as ocorrências em uma string. Mas no seu caso você só quer testar cada string apenas uma vez, de forma independente, então não faz sentido usá-la.

Comment: @SouLinuxlslife Cada regex tem seu próprio `lastIndex`, então a mudança só vale para a regex que vc usou. Se vc cria outra, ela tem seu próprio `lastIndex`, independente do outro

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, interessante que o lastindex não seja setado para zero ou "destruída" logo após o fim da execução do test, neste caso ele fica armazenado em memória para toda regex que eu testar?

Entendi lendo a documentação da Mozilla que lastindex será atualizado para cada instância que eu utilizar;

 https://developer-mozilla-org.translate.goog/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=pt&_x_tr_hl=pt-BR

Comment: Muito obrigado @hkotsubo!

Comment: @SouLinuxlslife Atualizei a resposta para deixar isso mais claro